# PHP cURL submit POST form after GET request

Tags: php, curl, request

I have the following problem.

I am making a cURL GET request to a page. On that page there is a POST form that I want to submit.
My question is how do I submit the form after the GET request is complete through the same curl handle ?

I cannot make a POST request directly since I get back a **Not Found** error.

Comment: Use ajax and a flag in DB and unlock the form with js after the cURL request is finished.

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer. can you provide an example of this? I have never done this before.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_ajax.asp

Comment: Hi @CiprianIvan, I think you question is possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code